# Drupal 7 Organic Groups, Drupal Commerce and Paypal

Tags: commerce, organic-groups, payment-gateways

I have a Drupal 7 site, with OG and commerce installed.  I have an og content type populated with content.  Everything is working as expected.  I found this link on Drupalcommerce:  https://drupalcommerce.org/blog/10809/selling-organic-groups-using-drupal-commerce and it is very close to what I'm after.  However, I don't want to charge the users for access to the group. I want to charge per group.  Just like meetup.com does.

In short, I would like for a user to:

1. Enter a group name Username and email
2. They are taken to Paypal to complete transaction
3. Paypal signals the transaction is complete
4. The group and user are created.

Any tutorial or guidance is appreciated.
Many thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out [Commerce Node Checkout Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_node_checkout) It gives you a basic **Pay to Pubish** workflow, which is exactly what you are try achieve.

As the project page says the module helps you

> Integrate with Commerce in order to allow you to charge users to
>   create nodes.

Comment: I did, but I need 10 more for it to show up.  Thanks again Gokul